Can the heat sink on a Peltier module be too large?
I need to cool a small container with a 5v power supply.
Let's say I use a common TEC1-12706 Peltier unit.  Normally it's around 2 ohm, so ~60 watts at 12v.  That equates to about 10w at 5v.  Which is fine, and should be adequate for my application.
However, another answer on this site suggests that it is possible for the heat-sink to be too large, as the unit "depends on the temperature difference of the two sides"?
Given that I'm underutilizing the unit, would I need to use less heat sinking to get the most from this unit at 5v?
Also, could I get better cooling for 5v if I used a higher watt unit like a TEC1-12710?

The answer is going to be more complicated than you think. Are you trying to reach the coldest temperature or are you trying to remove the most heat? And did you consider the current you have available for your solution?

Thanks for your comment, I'm happy to hear about any complications.  The goal is to keep the temperature in a tiny 5cm cube low, and to condense any moisture as quickly as possible.  Condensation will probably be the tougher challenge, so maximum heat removal is the primary goal.

That answer that you are referencing has to do with changing temperatures - if the heatsink is too big it has a lot of thermal inertia so it retains its temperature for a while. That's relevant to your application.

One complication is that because you are running the device at reduced capacity, you would need MORE heatsinking, not less. This seems counter-intuitive but you want the hot side as cool as possible to lower the temperature on your 5cm^3 chamber. This is because, for a given heat load, your delta T will be less do to the reduced performance. Of course, this all may or may not matter. Depends on your operating conditions -  how much heat is produced in the chamber? How insulated is the chamber? How cold do you need the chamber? What is the ambient temperature?

Thanks for your useful insight.  Chamber is quite well-insulated, although it receives a stream of warm humid air (35 degrees and 50% humidity) at ~300mL/min and I'd like to reduce the humidity as much as possible.  I suppose I could increase the voltage if absolutely necessary, but I think it would be simpler to up the power by using a lower-resistance peltier like 12710 or 12715?
